# Trigger not updating field on first time update?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have following trigger which runs on (after insert, after update, before update, before insert). The problem is SOQL query does not return anything on first time update. But when i update it second time then it return size.
I am unable to get why it is happening. Need your support what could be possible reason ?

Thanks

```
   trigger SharingCaseWithLA on Case (after insert, after update, before update, before insert) {

for(Case csRediness : trigger.new){

    List<Case> rediness = [Select id, Readiness_Activity_ID__r.ERS_ID__c, Readiness_Activity_ID__r.Course_Activity__r.Course_Name__c 
                           FROM Case WHERE Readiness_Activity_ID__c =: csRediness.Readiness_Activity_ID__c AND Readiness_Activity_ID__c != null];
        system.debug(rediness.size()); 

}                  


    }
```

Comment: What is `csRediness.Readiness_Activity_ID__c`? It is not declared anywhere

Comment: @Barcotter - csRediness is loop variable.

Comment: What loop? There is no loop in your code

Comment: @Barcotter- Please see updated code.

Comment: AHH! Queries in for loops! Code in Trigger body! At the very least you need to look into the `Aggregate-Query-Update` pattern.

Answer (score -2):

This trigger is firing on before insert also - are you sure that you are only looking for result after initial update ?

Edit - if you only perform the soql within a if(trigger.isupdate) condition you may get a more predictable result.

Comment: Did you intend to comment ?

Comment: Is probably both a comment and answer... I expect answer is that is looking at result of before insert. Will clarify

Comment: I have to update related object fields on Case. As far as i know you can not update related fields without querying it.